# SQLAlchemy Join Tables and Insert New Field into Every Row

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

So I'm new to SQLAlchemy and Python, but quite familiar with MySQL. I need to pull data out of a MySQL database from two different tables `beam_data` and `beam_unbracedlengths` to calculate a new value `lb`, then insert that `lb` back into `beam_data` as an additional field. I've gone ahead and used the ORM functionality to build my object in python with the correct final value `lb`. All I need to do is write this back to my database. When I `session.commit()`, I get no positive result in the database. Please help. Code and schematic, below:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import *
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
import fnmatch
import math

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@url:port/database')
connection = engine.connect()

# create a Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()
###################################################################
class beam(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'beam_data'
    BeamName = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    lb = Column(Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<beam(BeamName='%s', lb='%s')>" \
               % (self.BeamName, self.lb)

class bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'beam_unbracedlengths'
    BeamName = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    N1 = Column(String(50))
    N2 = Column(String(50))
    X = Column(mysql.DECIMAL(7, 3))
    Y = Column(mysql.DECIMAL(7, 3))
    Z = Column(mysql.DECIMAL(7, 3))
    X1 = Column(mysql.DECIMAL(7, 3))
    Y1 = Column(mysql.DECIMAL(7, 3))
    Z1 = Column(mysql.DECIMAL(7, 3))
    N1_grp = Column(String(100))
    N2_grp = Column(String(100))
    ElType = Column(String(3))
    # lb = Column(Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<bar(BeamName='%s', X=%s, Y=%s, Z=%s, X1=%s, Y1=%s, Z1=%s, " \
               "N1='%s', N2='%s, N1_grp='%s', N2_grp='%s, ElType='%s, lb='%s')>" \
               % (self.BeamName, self.X, self.Y, self.Z, self.X1, self.Y1, self.Z1,
                  self.N1, self.N2, self.N1_grp, self.N2_grp, self.ElType, self.lb)
###################################################################################

# give me all columns with bottom node braced
baseColumns = session.query(bar) \
    .filter(((bar.Z1 > bar.Z) & bar.N1_grp.like('%brc_strong%'))
            | ((bar.Z1 < bar.Z) & bar.N2_grp.like('%brc_strong%'))) \
    .filter(bar.ElType == 'COL') \
    .join(beam, bar.BeamName == beam.BeamName)
baseColumns = baseColumns.all()

for column in baseColumns:
    # initial length of column
    lb = math.sqrt((column.X1 - column.X)**2 + (column.Y1 - column.Y)**2 + (column.Z1 - column.Z)**2)
    topNodeGrp = ''
    columns = []

    # if the top node is found to be braced, break
    while not fnmatch.fnmatch(topNodeGrp, '*brc_strong*'):

        # keep track of all BeamNames composing our column
        columns.append(column)

        # store the current column name
        prevName = column.BeamName

        # which node is on top? and is it braced?
        if column.Z1 > column.Z:
            topNode = column.N2
            topNodeGrp = column.N2_grp
        else:
            topNode = column.N1
            topNodeGrp = column.N1_grp
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(topNodeGrp, '*brc_strong*'):
            break

        # if it isn't braced at the top, then find the column above it
        column = session.query(bar) \
            .filter(bar.N1.like(topNode) | bar.N2.like(topNode)) \
            .filter(bar.BeamName != prevName) \
            .filter(bar.ElType == 'COL') \
            .join(beam, bar.BeamName == beam.BeamName).first()

        # add the length from the column above to the previous column
        lb = lb + math.sqrt((column.X1 - column.X)**2 + (column.Y1 - column.Y)**2 + (column.Z1 - column.Z)**2)

    # write unbraced length value to all segments of column
    for segment in columns:
        segment.lb = lb
        session.add(segment)

session.commit()
```

[image]

Comment: If you need to update a column for every row, why not just write a `UPDATE SET lb = ...` in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

So I can append two lines to the bottom of the last for loop in my code:

```
# write unbraced length value to all segments of column
for segment in columns:
    segment.lb = lb
    session.add(segment)
    upd = update(beam_data).where(beam_data.c.BeamName == segment.BeamName).values(lb=lb)
    connection.execute(upd)
```

and it works, but this is laboriously long. I assume there is a smarter way to write the entire column to the table, rather than updating individual values.